# Why the Cocoapods installation process does not proceed ahead

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, git, cocoapods

Why the Cocoapods installation process does not proceed ahead. When it reaches about 70% or 80% it slows down the speed of receiving object and after a few minutes it stops downloading and gives this error. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwpgE.png)

Comment: Have you tried Cocoapods with different library?

Comment: Can we get a little more information on your issue? I'm assuming you're typing `sudo gem install cocoapods` into your Terminal and then getting this issue?

Comment: It can be due to internet connectivity issue. When we are doing setup of COCOPOD lots of files are being downloaded. So in some part of time connection loose this can happen. I am facing this issue on One of my system of home where internet speed is slow. and working fine in my company system.

Comment: @Poles I have to use firebase, so i am using pod 'Firebase/Core'. If there is any alternate suggest me. thanx

Comment: @kgaleman No dear after typing Pod setup I am getting this issue, I am very much worried. you can see the snapshot in status.

Comment: @Wolverine I have tried on 4G network in office as well as in home but still same issue. any idea for suggestion?

Comment: go to **~/.cocoapods** and remove all files there. and then try to uninstall and install cocoa pod and again try to setup.